# Getting Exception on using AWS S3 sdk with openstack to get all buckets/containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openstack

I am getting Exception on using AWS S3 SDK with OpenStack to get all buckets/containers.

Expected Behavior

```
I should be able get list of buckets from OpenStack using aws s3 sdk using .net Core as it is working fine in dotnet 4.72 framework.
```

Current Behavior

```
I'm getting exception while fetching list of buckets from OpenStack using S3 sdk.
AWS s3 sdk is working fine with .net 4.72 frameworks
```

Possible Solution

```
Is there any incompatibility between dotnet core and openstack ?
```

Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

```
Create a simple dotnet core application and try to fetch list of buckets using AWS s3 credentials.
```

Context

```
dotnet 4.72 was working fine but now after migrating to dotnet core it is not working.
```

Your Environment

```
AWSSDK.Core version used: 3.3.100
Service assembly and version used:
Operating System and version: Windows 10
Visual Studio version: VS 2015
```

Targeted .NET platform: dotnet core
.NET Core Info
.NET Core version used for development: dotnet core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response using GitHub ticket :

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1246

```
Hi. We do not make any guarantees on how the SDK behaves with non-S3 service. 
Please re-open the issue if you can reproduce the problem against S3.
```